# Pop images with fancybox - REACT JS

Tags: reactjs, fancybox

Task:
most of the content is fed from the Django CMS, that including images.
I would like to add a class to every link/image so it'd be poped up via the fancybox script, class="fancybox" like I've done countless of times on countless of regular websites.

I'd like to achieve same functionality in this REACT JS project I've been working on for some time now.

I've installed react-fancybox module via NPM and import it into one React module (namely "ArticleBlock" since I dont' know how to import it globally):*import Fancybox from 'react-fancybox';*

and added css to my global CSS file, as the simple go-through suggests.
*@import "~react-fancybox/dist/react-fancybox.css";*
([react-fancybox component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-fancybox))

At the end I added class "fancybox" to one of the images in the CMS. The result is not what I've expected, as the image seems to be taken out of the DOM itself and is rendered poped-up right from the start.

***Note:*** if I add class to the rest of the images, four in total, all of them will be rendered poped-up and taken out of the DOM.

This illustrates the behavior of the component:
[image]

What am I doing wrong and how could I fix the default behavior of the fancybox component?

Comment: Looking at the screenshot, it seems that CSS rules are not applied. So, check if CSS file is really loaded.

Comment: CSS is loaded, all required classes are visible in the code inspector.